# Server does not remove/disconnect socket when Client disconnects

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I've been working on a chat room.

Multi Threaded Server accepts the clients

```
    btnConnect.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try{


                int port = 2345;
                ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
                System.out.println("Waiting for clients");
                Thread thread = new Thread(){
                    public void run(){
                        while(true){
                            Socket socket;
                            try {
                                socket = server.accept();
                                gui.AddUserToList(socket);
                                ConnectionArray.add(socket);
                                ChatClient chat = new ChatClient(socket,gui);
                                Thread x = new Thread(chat);
                                x.start();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }
                };
                thread.start();
            }
            catch(IOException error){
                System.out.println(error);
            }


        }
    });
```

When the connect button is pressed it will run an infinite loop to accept clients. For each client it connects, it ads it to a ListArray called *AddUserToList*.

A ChatClient is made and the object is passed in the Thread constructor.

```
public void isConnected(){
    if(!socket.isConnected()){

        for(int i = 1; i <= GUI.ConnectionArray.size(); i++){

            if(GUI.ConnectionArray.get(i) == socket){
                GUI.ConnectionArray.remove(i);
                gui.updateList();

            }
        }

    }
}


@Override
public void run() {
    try
    {
        try
        {
            input = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

            while(true)
            {
                isConnected();
                if(!input.hasNext())
                    return;



                message = input.nextLine();


                for(int i = 1; i <= GUI.ConnectionArray.size(); i++){
                    Socket tmpSocket = (Socket) GUI.ConnectionArray.get(i-1);
                    PrintWriter tmpOut = new PrintWriter(tmpSocket.getOutputStream());
                    tmpOut.println(message);
                    tmpOut.flush();
                    //System.out.println("Sent");


                }                   
            }

        }
        finally
        {
            socket.close();
        }
    }
    catch(IOException io){
        System.out.println(io);
    }

}
```

If there is are no messages coming then it should check the connection. When I disconnect on my client.

```
            while(true)
            {
                isConnected();
                if(!input.hasNext())
                    return;
```

This line should go back since nothing is being sent, so why does the program get stuck trying to listen on messages?

Is there really no way to close a socket? Because I need to remove the user/socket from the ArrayList and then update it to show me that there is no client connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check for the end of stream condition on all your reads and Scanner invocations. You aren't doing that anywhere. The `isConnected()` method doesn't do that. It only tells you whether *you* ever connected *this socket.*. It doesn't magically become false when the peer disconnects. Neither does `isClosed()` magically become true at that time.

Comment: Hey sorry, I'm kind of a newbie to socket programming. I googled "stream conditions Java" and could not find any resources to extend your answer. 
You're right, I also Googles the isConnected() method and other people have stated the same thing you said. 

I'm just lost at "stream conditions" , "Scanner invocations" and "DLLs". 

Sorry if I that sounds naïve

Comment: `read()` returns -1 at end of stream; `hasNext()` and `hasNextLine()` return false; `readLine() returns null.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had done if(message == null) and it worked, since it returns false! THANKS :D